# Generate random list with specefic items in python

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a randomly filled fix-sized list of integers using only some predefined numbers to choose from. Also, the sum of the numbers in this new list has to be equal to a given number.

For example: randomly repeat these 3 numbers `-2`, `2`, `3` to create a new list with size `20` and the sum of list items has to be `60`. In this example, `size = 20`, `sum = 60`, and `numbers = [-2, 2, 3]` are inputs.

Can I do this in python?

Comment: Yes you can do it in python

Comment: you can if you try!!!!

Comment: @Nihal I tried, but I think maybe need a heuristic algorithm to solve that, what do think?

Comment: @AmitNanaware with a library?

Comment: @Aprilis Yes you can use [random library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


def sum_to_x(n, x):
    values = [0.0, x] + list(np.random.uniform(high=x, size=n - 1))
    values.sort()
    return [values[i + 1] - values[i] for i in range(n)]


d = sum_to_x(20, 60)
print(d)
print(sum(d))
```

output:

```
[1.1666321716192374, 3.7356682360404636, 0.10213495009527396, 15.944355221343475, 4.823749563474106, 2.771274835477797, 1.1543877569990038, 6.6231006904687675, 1.0517272997350275, 6.954578248764335, 0.9446793094979142, 2.079080332702951, 1.1813248101489293, 3.3584697034830597, 0.8048689399051554, 1.3952223726127002, 4.797652596772288, 0.30201710006423355, 0.5143495684426824, 0.29472629235259973]
60.0
```

**for integer values:**

```
import random as r

def random_sum_to(n, num_terms=None):
    num_terms = (num_terms or r.randint(2, n)) - 1
    a = r.sample(range(1, n), num_terms) + [0, n]
    list.sort(a)
    return [a[i + 1] - a[i] for i in range(len(a) - 1)]


print(random_sum_to(60, 20))
```

**output:**

```
[3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 6, 1, 12, 2]
60
```

Comment: The question states that the input numbers are given as parameters; this solution does not take that into account.

Comment: i didn't noticed that,

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you should know that this is a complex problem to solve it in optimal time.

I can only give you a random solution, which may take a lot of time in some cases, because it is, you know, random:

```
import random

def create_list(possible_values, size, sum_of_values, max_iterations=10**5):
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        values = [
            random.choice(possible_values)
            for _ in range(size)]

        if sum(values) == sum_of_values:
            # only exit once it reaches the goal
            print('solution found after {:,d} iterations'.format(i))
            return values

    raise ValueError(
        'no solution found after {:,d} iterations'.format(max_iterations))
```

Here is a demonstration; the same parameters may have a different durations in each invocation of the function

```
>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 20, 30)
solution found after 38 iterations
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 20, 30)
solution found after 31 iterations
[2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, -1, 3, 3, 0, 1]
>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 20, 30)
solution found after 93 iterations
[2, -1, 2, 1, 3, 2, -1, 0, 2, -1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3]

>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1, 2], 20, 30)
solution found after 50,456 iterations
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1]
```

If it fails, you can try again with a higher number of iterations, but it does not always solve the issue:

```
>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1], 20, 30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ralf/PycharmProjects/django_test_02/run_pw.py", line 20, in create_list
    'no solution found after {:,d} iterations'.format(max_iterations))
ValueError: no solution found after 100,000 iterations

>>> create_list([-1, 0, 1], 20, 30, 10**6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ralf/PycharmProjects/django_test_02/run_pw.py", line 20, in create_list
    'no solution found after {:,d} iterations'.format(max_iterations))
ValueError: no solution found after 1,000,000 iterations
```